# jQuery draggable - drag an item

Tags: jquery, overflow, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I want to make my draggable item to the connected sortable list. I found if the connected sortable list is overflow the div with `overflow:auto` style, the draggable item cannot be dragged in to it. Is it a bug?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My MultiSelect</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js">
</script>
<style>
ul{ border: solid 2px yellow; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height: 100px; overflow:auto;">
please scroll to bottom to test bug<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<ul><li id="drag">draggable item</li></ul>
<ul id="sort">
 <li>a</li>
 <li>b</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#sort").sortable();
$("#drag").draggable({
connectToSortable: "#sort",
revert: 'invalid'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like a bug to me

another addition: if you drag your draggable out of the div before you try to add it to the sortable it works too

a possible workaround would be the same as the [shopping cart example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart) at the jQuery UI demo-section. this will not let you sort the items right away on drag (as they will be appended to the sortable on drop) but it will generate a functional and extendable sortable

source:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My MultiSelect</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#drag>li").draggable({
                revert: 'invalid',
                helper: 'clone'
            });
            $('#sort').droppable({
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                    $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
                }
            }).sortable({
                items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
                sort: function() {
                    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
                }
            }); 
        });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul{ 
                border: solid 2px grey; 
                width:200px;
            } 
            #main{
                border:solid 1px #cdcdcd;
                width:400px;
                height: 100px;
                overflow:auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
        please scroll to bottom to test bug<br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <ul id="drag">
            <li>draggable item</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="sort">
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```